# Using the Request callback in NPM to call additional functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was wondering if it's possible to have the request package to perform callbacks after call backs.

Below is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
getToken().then(function(accessToken) {
  var deferred = q.defer();
  try{
    var accessToken = accessToken
    console.log('The token is: '+ accessToken)
    return deferred.promise;
  }catch(error){
    deferred.reject(error);
    console.log(error)
  }
}.then(function facebookRequest(token))
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use request-promise, its made exactly for this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise

Example:

```
requestPromise('http://www.google.com')
    .then(function (htmlString) {
        // Process html... 
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        // Crawling failed... 
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, have just learnt how to use request so will try to use request-promise now!

So much to learn for a beginner who has just started with javascript not so long ago!

Comment: its really easy, its just request, but with promises, very nice